# Foundation file to import not found or unreadable

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, yeoman, bower

Using the new Yeoman beta 1.0
I bootstrapped an angular application, and installed foundation via bower.

When I run my server, I get this error:

```
error app/styles/main.scss (Line 7 of app/components/foundation/scss/foundation.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: modular-scale.
```

The import is `@import "modular-scale";`

I tried to change that to `@import "foundation/functions/modular-scale";`

But got a loop warning then, saying it was trying to import itself.

Tried adding the ruby gem 'modular-scale' in my grunt file, under compass with
`require: 'modular-scale'`

But it doesn't seem to work either

Anyways, I am not sure what to do here.

Comment: Do you have the modular-scale gem installed?

Comment: Yes, i do have it installed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when migrating an app to 1.0. Bower was installing the components into a top-level components directory instead of at app/components. If that is the case, one fix is to add a file `.bowerrc` with

```
{
    "directory": "app/components"
}
```

I'm not sure the root cause, as creating a new webapp with Yeoman 1.0 doesn't suffer from this problem.